# Convert int[] into ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

What is best way recopying `int[]` array elements into `ArrayList`?

I need to do this fast so what would be the fastest way?

Comment: Hm, isn't `Arrays.asList` sufficient?

Comment: *"I need to do this fast"*  Fast in typing the code or fast in execution?  The latter should be tested at run-time, but given the deep amount of thought/research that seemed to go into the question, I suspect you mean the former.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Arrays#asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to create *"a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)"*

```
Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 42}; // cannot use int[] here
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(intArray);
```

Alternatively, to decouple the two data structures:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(intArray.length);

for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++)
{
    intList.add(intArray[i]);
}
```

Or even more tersely:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<Integer>();` could be `new ArrayList<Integer>(intArray.length);` to avoid reallocate array

Comment: Pulsar has a point: This doesn't work because `Arrays.asList(intArray)` returns `List<int[]>`. So it seems we actually have to use a loop here, or can we somehow convert an `int[]` into an `Integer[]` array?

Comment: @NiklasB. indeed. Edited; `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` will do the trick.

Comment: Well yeah, but the question was about an `int[]` array specifically :) But of course OP can just skip the first sample if it doesn't work him/her.

Comment: @MattBall Does your last method actually work? for `List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(intArray);` I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer>`

Comment: @likejiujitsu you missed a spot. Read carefully.

Comment: The last line is misleading. Firstly you don't need new ArrayList<Integer> if you already dealing with Integer, not int, and secondly that is the whole point - the question is about int[], not Integer[]

Answer (score 19):

ArrayList is not the best storage for primitives such as int. ArrayList stores objects not primitives. There are libraries out there for Lists with primitives.
If you really want to store all primitive `int` as an`Integer` object you will have to convert them one by one using `Integer.valueOf(...)` (so you don't create extra Integer instances when not needed).

While you can do this:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

You cannot do this:

```
int[] i = { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(i); // this will get you List<int[]>
```

as an array is actually an object as well an treated as such in var-args when using primitives such as int. Object arrays works though:

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(new Object[2]);
```

So something along the lines of:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  list.add(Integer.valueOf(array[i]));
```

Comment: Hm, you're right. I wonder why nobody else has brought this up earlier :)

Comment: You don't need to do Integer.valueOf() anymore since Java 1.5 and autoboxing.

Comment: That's true @ZeroOne, autoboxing generates Integer.valueOf() for us.

Answer (score 6):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), you don't need to bother with the `Integer[]`:

```
int[] array;
List<Integer> list = Ints.asList(array);
```

and if you want an `ArrayList`, that's just

```
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(Ints.asList(array));
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Otherwise, if all you have is an `int[]`, you have to do it the old-fashioned way:

```
int[] array;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
for (int val : array) {
  list.add(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide an alternate answer as well, depending on how the List is used this could perform better (creation is faster, and only the actually used ints are converted, but they are always converted not just the first time, so repeated get of the same element is worse). Create a simple wrapper list around the array:

```
final int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
List list = new AbstractList<Integer>() {

     public Integer get(int index) {
       return array[index];
     }

     public Integer set(int index, Integer value) {
       //or just throw new UnsupportedOperationException("..."); if not needed
       Integer old = array[index];
       array[index] = value;
       return old;
     }

     public int size() {
       return array.length;
     }
};
```

or in a method creating it for you:

```
static List<Integer> asList(final int[] array) {
  return new AbstractList<Integer>() { ...
             };
}
```