# how to convert int[] to ArrayList

Tags: java

I want to know how convert `int[]` to `Integer[]` in java.

Basically i am trying to convert `int[]` to `ArrayList` in java.

I found some examples but they are based on `Integer` object and not based on `int[]`.

referred:
[Convert int[] into ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269300/convert-int-into-arraylist)

Thanks

Comment: Traverse each element in your `int[]` and add it to your `List<Integer>`.

Comment: You cannot use generics like the `List<T>` interface and the `ArrayList<T>` class with primitive types as `int`.  You have to use the boxed type `Integer`.

Comment: is there any other way other than this. because if I use traverse ,this will be in loop which i am going to iterate over 10k times,not sure how it is going to impact

Comment: use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) and then use it to initialize an `ArrayList` if you need additional functionality

Comment: If you use the `Integer.valueOf(int)` method, the `Integer` instances are cached, so you do not create many objects, if that was your concern.

Comment: Do you really need an ArrayList, or is any List implementation sufficient?

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
int[] array = ...;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
for (int i : array) list.add(i);
```

Note the parameter to the constructor. This will set the initial capacity of the underlying array to what it will need, for best performance.

Comment: What's wrong with just using Arrays.asList(myArray)? I know the underlying array will be the given array but why should we create a new array?

Comment: @Alfredo Osorio: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248763/arrays-aslist-of-an-array

Comment: Ok got it, you won't be able to modify the list. If it is just for read only operations you would be fine. +1

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio: Nope, I think you didn't understand. It would create a `List<int[]>` with one element, which is the array itself.

Comment: your code will give ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Exception

Comment: I do think that OP already knows this answer. As he has already mentioned about such an answer by linking it in his question.

Comment: @Suganthan: Why do you think that?

Comment: @ Martijn Courteaux just try iterate a predefined array, throwing exception. When adding the index it is fine, when try to access the element from particular index it will throw exception

Comment: @ Martijn Courteaux if you don't mind you can try in the code that I posted above

Comment: @Suganthan: I really don't know what you are thinking, but this works perfectly fine... http://ideone.com/GSJIUj

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux you are right, when accessing the index element we have to access like this list.add(array[i-1]),first I tried list.add(array[i]), so it causes the problem.

Comment: @Suganthan: You should really read about the for each loop in Java. http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your `int`s into an `Integer` object because you cannot create a`List<int>` list.

```
int[] array = new int[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  list.add(Integer.valueOf(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i : yourArray) {
    yourArrayList.add(i);
}
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] old = something;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int x : old){
    list.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use guava's newArrayList() for this.

Comment: Which one? Neither of the overloaded methods accepts an int[]!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a `List<Integer>` out of an `int[]`, and performance is your concern (so all other provided answers here are still 'too slow' for you), you can write a custom `List<Integer>` implementation that is directly backed by the `int[]`:

```
public class IntegerList extends AbstractList<Integer> implements List<Integer> {
    private final int[] data;

    public IntegerList(int[] data) { this.data = data; }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) { return data[index]; }

    @Override
    public int size() { return data.length; }
}

// usage
List<Integer> myIntegerList = new IntegerList(myIntArray);
```

The drawbacks are:

- The list is not modifiable
- Changes of the underlying `int[]` will affect the list instance.
- Creating `Integer` objects out of your `int`s will still happen, it is just deferred until `get(int)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils` from the Apache Commons Lang library to convert the `int[]`  to an `Integer[]` and then use `Arrays.asList()` to back the Array in a List:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

int[] array = ...;
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));
```